# Prepare for the German examination

Tags: standard-german

Ich will mich für die Prüfung für das [Große Deutsche Sprachdiplom](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/nc2/deindex.htm?wt_sc=gds) vorbereiten.

Wisst ihr wo ich online Prüfungsmodulare finden kann?

Kennt jemand das Buch: "Fromme/Guess, Fit fürs Goethe-Zertifikat C2. Lehrbuch mit integrierter Audio-CD: Großes Deutsches Sprachdiplom"? Wisst ihr, ob es auch eine online Version davon gibt?

---

I want to prepare myself for the examination of [Große Deutsche Sprachdiplom](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/nc2/deindex.htm?wt_sc=gds).

Do you know where I can find online tests for it?

Do you know the book: "Fromme/Guess, Fit fürs Goethe-Zertifikat C2. Lehrbuch mit integrierter Audio-CD: Großes Deutsches Sprachdiplom"?

Is there also an online version of it?

**EDIT** :

What subject do you think is possible for the writting part and which subject is possible for the oral part for this year at the examination?

Comment: Prüfungsmodulare?

Comment: The publisher, Hueber Verlag, [still has the book in its catalogue](https://shop.hueber.de/de/fit-f-goethe-z-c2-lb-m-integ-cd.html). It appears that they only sell a printed version (with the audio CDs).

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine once asked in Goethe-Institut directly, because she is a teacher in GI of her country and needed that C2 exam. The answer then (2013) was:

> You have to buy it, there's no free material available online.

Goethe-Institut won't give you directly the material either. There is no official source providing this tests.

Comment: Ok. Could you maybe ask your friend what subject she thinks is possible for the writting part and which subject is possible for the oral part for this year at the examination? It would be great!! @c.p.

Comment: @MaryStar The subjects are not 'officially' constrained, as far as I know. But in class, we made a pair of tests for which a somehow basic but good understanding of politics was needed. As I was told in GI, they expect not only proficiency in German, but also some knowledge about daily life in Germany: thus, it can be essential, say, to read and fully understand a text, that you know, say, in which *Bundesland* lies XY-city, and otherwise it'd be difficult to answer. Take a German newspaper and the odds are that if you almost fully understand random articles, you'd be doing good the test.

Answer (score 4):

Goethe Institut offers additional material on its [website](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/nc2/mat/deindex.htm), including "sample exams", partly free, partly for sale.

Regarding the book: There seems to be no official online / e-book version, just the printed edition. Please remember that any third party making this book available online would be violating copyright laws. So even if it does exist in some obscure corner of the Internet, we can't and won't link you there.

You can't learn a language (at least not on C2 level) without learning about the culture behind it. So, like c.p. said, if you can understand what's going on in random newspaper articles, you should be fine. Keeping the exam subject secret is common practice – on C2 level, you should be able to talk and write about "every" subject that pops up. You won't be expected to know very specific technical terms – many native speakers won't either – but a good vocabulary is essential. (We are talking about the highest level, after all.) There is one announced topic, though: If you choose "Literature" for the module "Schreiben", you should have worked through this year's [literature list](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/nc2/mat/de8750189.htm).

Answer (score 1):

What about Google? Google Books in the first place, and by the way, Google seems to be a search engine, too...

http://books.google.at/books?id=ciKNjqdUaVcC

As it is only a preview, there are pages missing throughout. At least you can check if the content suites you. But there is also a Russian site providing a pdf. For a short amount of time, I had placed these links here, now I have removed them out of a general consideration concerning copyright issues; as the compiler of those pdfs took great pains scanning every single page, I think this must have been due to poor availability of this kind of learning material in Russia. Nevertheless, in a case of emergency, the OP will be able to find the link on her or his own, whereas under normal conditions, the pdf won't serve its purpose anywhere near the original.